# Django queryset objects return None instead of 0 even though the database has 0 stored as the field value

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, mysql-python

I encountered a problem when I started using mysql-connector/python instead of mysqlclient for my Django project. Suddenly values stored as 0 in the database is turned to "None" in the resulting queryset, here's an example.

```
queryset = Invoices.objects.all().filter(sold=0)
print(queryset[0].sold)  # Prints "None"
```

Where the same statement would have printed 0 with mysqlclient.

Is there a good way to fix this? I haven't gotten mysqlclient to work well with my current setup and would rather not have to track down all the calls depending on a 0-value and restructure it to handle Nonetypes.

Edit with the model in question:

```
from django.db import models
from authentication.models import Account, SubUser


class Invoices(models.Model):
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    debtor = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
    debtorname = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='soldinvoices', null=False)
    dateout = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    expiration = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='boughtinvoices', null=True)
    fid = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    approved = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    paid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    subseller = models.ForeignKey(SubUser, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    askingprice = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Sold, Paid, and Approved all come back as None, even though they can be queried using 0 as a value.

Additional example:

```
my_foo = Foo(bar=0)
my_foo.save()
print(my_foo.bar)  # prints 0
```

Separate queries using mysql-connector-python yields 0 as expected in the queryset.

Django version 2.0.3.0, mysql-connector-python version 8.0.12.

Comment: Can you please share your model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added it to the post!

Comment: Looks like there is no `status` field here. Are you sure this is not an *attribute* (some logic at the Django side)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That was just an example, should have been clearer about that, will edit the post with the actual query!

Comment: Can you add version numbers for django and mysql-connector to your question?

Comment: @Angela added to post

Comment: Can you also add your mysql-connector connection code to the question? Have you uninstalled mysqlclient from your apps VE ?

Comment: @Angela I had no custom mysql-connector code in the project, the framework makes all queries, but I might have misunderstood the question. 
mysqlclient wasn't installed. I did however get it working by switching to mysql 5.7 and mysqlclient 1.3.12

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still running into this  problem (as I did), I found a solution that worked for me. In the database configuration in the `settings.py` file, add the following option:

```
'OPTIONS': {'use_pure': True }
```

This resolved the problem for me.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

pass null argument to all those fields.

Comment: How do you mean,  `sold = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)`? The value of the field isnt null, it's 0. When querying the database using mysql separately the value is indeed stored as 0