# Django python manage.py runserver outputs Performing system checks... then exits without error code, with mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, database-connection

I've been trying to solve database problems with Django for a while, I gave up on using mysqlclient because it just wouldn't install properly, but with mysql-connector-python [another bug appeared as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51920779/django-queryset-objects-return-none-instead-of-0-even-though-the-database-has-0).

When trying to solve the mysqlclient problems [another issue was encountered as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926091/django-mysqlclient-backend-produces-django-db-utils-operationalerror-2059-nu).

Now I've downgraded to python 3.5.2, using Django 2.0.3.0, mysqlclient 1.3.12, and mysql version 8.0.12.

Now I get no error code, when I try to use `python manage.py runserver`
this is what comes back from the terminal:

```
(venv) D:\Program\LiquidMarket>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...


(venv) D:\Program\LiquidMarket>
```

No error code, it just stops, any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: are you able to access the site before it stops?

Comment: What happens when you change your DB settings to the default one (the `sqlite` settings)?

Comment: @user2906838 No, it stops almost immediately. 
JerinPeterGeorge other settings work, such as the mysql-connector-python, so it seems to be the mysqlclient that has a problem

Comment: Does `python -Wall manage.py runserver` give any more information?

Answer (score 1):

Enter error lines or just remove database settings from your settings.py file and see if you get any error on your console.

If you don't see any error then something seriously wrong with your windows machine :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by downgrading mysql to 5.7.

Working setup: Windows 10, python 3.6.6, mysqlclient 1.3.12, mysql 5.7